# react responsive design background colors aren't the same as desktop

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, chakra-ui

I'm developing a website and wanted to make it responsive.
I'm having some problems though with the color for the background.

I see the page as I want it to look but after deploying it to firebase and viewing it on the phone the background colors change dramatically.

The first image is how it turns out and the second is how I want it to be.

[image: how I want it]

[image: how it turn out]

Any ideas? I'm using react and chakra ui.

Comment: I guess chakra-ui features include dark/light theme. The first figure is a dark theme, and the second one is a light theme. Maybe chakra-ui changes the theme based on devices, if this is correct, y should make theme to be fixed to avoid chakra-ui changing theme dynamically

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I actually removed the option to switch between color schemes, could it still affect the app?

Comment: Yeah, my sus is because dark mode effect... try to change your browser to dark mode..

if your app change to same color as mobile app, so thats dark mode effect

and can u share sandbox/code, so we can investigate why that happen

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { extendTheme } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { colors } from "./colors";

const activeLabelStyles = {
  transform: "scale(0.9) translateY(-25px)",
  color: "#26282ac9",
};

const config = {
  initialColorMode: "light",
  useSystemColorMode: false,
};


const theme = extendTheme({
  config,
  styles: {
    global: {
      direction: "ltr",
      "html, body": {
        lineHeight: "tall",
        margin: "0px",
        padding: "0px",
        color: colors.bunkerBlack,
      },
    },
    fonts: {
      heading: `Playfair Display', serif`,
    },
  },

  components: {
    Form: {
      variants: {
        floating: {
          container: {
            _focusWithin: {
              label: {
                ...activeLabelStyles,
              },
            },
            "input:not(:placeholder-shown) + label, .chakra-select__wrapper + label, textarea:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label":
              {
                ...activeLabelStyles,
              },
            label: {
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              zIndex: 2,
              position: "absolute",
              backgroundColor: "white",
              pointerEvents: "none",
              mx: 3,
              px: 1,
              my: 2,
              transformOrigin: "left top",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  breakpoints: {
    sm: "22.563em",
    md: "25.9em",
    lg: "80.5em",
    xl: "120em",
  },
});

export default theme;
```

This is how I wrote the color mode in the themes.js
and below I implement it in app.js:

```js
import React from "react";
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import themes from "./styles/themes.js";

import "./styles/main.css";
import routes from "./config/routes.js";

function App() {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider theme={themes}>
      <Routes>
        {routes.map((route) => (
          <Route path={route.path} key={route.path} element={route.component} />
        ))}
      </Routes>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Everything else works and when I see the application on the browser I get the correct colors, even when I go down to the mobile version, only when I open it with the phone do I receive the incorrect colors...

Thank you!

Comment: The color mode (dark/light) is cached in localStorage, so chakra UI has used cached color mode instead of initialColorMode in config. 
for quick, I think, can clear cached color mode like
`useUpdateEffect(() => { localStorage.removeItem("chakra-ui-color-mode"); }, []);`
but you also can find other clean ways.

Comment: still not working... apart from what you mentioned I also added  

 <ColorModeScript initialColorMode={theme.config.initialColorMode} />

in themes:

const config = {
  initialColorMode: "light",
  useSystemColorMode: false,
};